# installing python3.3.3 on virtual environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv, distribute

I was using ubuntu 13.04. So python 2.7 is already installed in my system.I need to install python 3.3.3 on my system for a new project.There existed virtual environment in my system.the versions of virtual envs are

```
virtualenv==1.10.1
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.1.1
distribute==0.6.49
```

which is installed on my /usr/local/bin path.So now I need to install python 3.3.3 on my existing environment created with these virtual envs using distribute.Is it possible to install python 3.3.3 with these versions of virtual env or whether I need to upgrade the environments? Please help me.I need the whole steps in installation procedure.
Is this code satisfied virtualenv --python=python3.3 test --distribute python 3.3

**Also tell me the best version of django to be used with python 3.3 version**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it on my local machine - it does work.

Since [Python3 support was added with django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.5/#python-3-support) I recommend it and everything above.

> ...Django 1.5 is also the first release with Python 3 support!...